# Install GRUB on LFS USB drive

Tags: boot, grub, usb-drive, lfs

I have built a Linux From Scratch system onto a flash drive with the kernel and everything. When I boot into it via the GRUB instance on the host computer's hard drive, it works fine.  I would like to install. GRUB on the flash. drive, as to not need the host computer's instance of GRUB. There is a /boot folder on the USB that contains a working grub config file, and it seems that the only thing missing is grub itself. (I also would like to have it Legacy BIOS compatible as for it to be bootable on more types of systems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dangerous commands ahead, you may hurt your system. You can do this from a live cd to be on the safe side.

1. Mount the USB, say under `/mnt`.
2. Take note of the USB device, say `/dev/sdb`, which will be used in the commands below.
3. Install `grub-efi-amd64`.
4. Mark `/dev/sdb1` as bootable, you can use a disk utility.
5. Execute

```
  $ dirs=(dev etc usr lib lib64 bin sbin sys proc)
  $ for dir in ${dirs[@]}; do mkdir /mnt/$dir && sudo mount --bind /$dir /mnt/$dir; done
  $ sudo chroot /mnt/
  # grub-install --force --removable --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/ /dev/sdb1
  # grub-install --force --removable --target=i386-pc --boot-directory=/ /dev/sdb
  # exit
  $ for dir in ${dirs[@]}; do sudo umount /mnt/$dir && rm -r /mnt/$dir; done
```

Now both efi and legacy GRUB will be installed, the bootable `grub.cfg` is under `/boot/grub`. If the file already exists make a backup.

Comment: Thanks, this works on a different flash drive I have. Before I do it on the real one, I would like to know, does this erase/modify dev/sdb1 because that's where the actual LFS system is built and I do not want to ruin it.

Comment: @MatthiasLee I think not, it's been a while since I been doing this. Can you make a backup of the USB?

Comment: Yeah, I can. Also, do I still need to mount the drive if I only am doing the non-efi (--target=i386-pc)? Edit: I don't need EFI

Comment: @MatthiasLee If you don't need efi just don't execute `grub-install --force --removable --target=x86_64-efi...`. The rest stays the same.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Will do once my backup completes

Comment: It works, is there any way to make grub automatically load a config file on the USB instead of booting to the command line?

Comment: @MatthiasLee yes, if I'm not mistaken, create a `grub.cfg` file under `/grub` with the content `set root=(hd0,1)`, under that line `configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Now in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` add the proper entries.

Comment: I did that, and it still just boots up to the grub command line and I need to load the config manually

Comment: @MatthiasLee mmh, let me see...

Comment: Just FYI, if you want a quick way to make a bit-for-bit copy of a drive, just do something like `dd if=<path-to-usb-device-file> of=backup.img status=progress`. Super handy stuff, it'll even copy bootloaders etc over into the image for you. Works absolutely wonderfully! Just, you know, don't mix up the paths or make any typos. That can be bad - really bad. `dd` is one of my favorite tools for that reason - it really does not care what is on the disk, just puts it where you ask it to.

Comment: @MatthiasLee if there's an error in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` you wil get a bash console. What are its contents?